# Preferred way of aggregating logs

Tags: fluentd, google-kubernetes-engine

What would be the best way to handle logs on Google Container Engine? By looking at the running pods I can see that every node is automatically running a `fluentd`service. Can we tap into that to get our logs into Developer Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fluentd container running on each node automatically collects the stdout and stderr of your pods and sends them to the Google Cloud Logging API. The only wrinkle is that the logs won't actually be saved by the logging API unless you've enabled the API for your project, which you can do [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/apiview/logging/overview?_ga=1.180471783.1743530058.1430414603).

Once you've done that, the logs should show up in [their normal place in the Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/logs).

Comment: Your 2nd link goes to a corporate Google login page